# Is there a Photo Mode in Final Fantasy VII Remake?

Tags: final-fantasy-7-remake

In Horizon Zero Dawn there is a photo mode that allows you to manipulate the camera and obtain unique, creative screenshots. I am looking for a similar capability in Final Fantasy VII Remake. There are tons of great opportunities to capture interesting photos, with unique locations, characters, weapon and materia configurations, and lighting effects. Does this photo mode capability exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the *Intergrade* update released in June 2021, Final Fantasy 7 Remake now has a [Photo Mode](https://gamerant.com/final-fantasy-7-remake-intergrade-photo-mode-take-pictures/amp/). To access this mode, simply open the party menu and press the square button.

Since this feature is apart of the *Intergrade* update, this is only available on the PS5. The PS4 still unfortunately lacks photo mode.

---

<strike>Unfortunately no. At the time of writing, Final Fantasy VII Remake does not have a designated photo mode. When it comes to taking photos, you are at the mercy of the consoles standard screenshot options.</strike>